# Mongoosejs refresh a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a document for example: var doc = Model.findOne({name:"name"});

Now if the document gets edited trough another connection the the database, doc doesn't hold the right information. I do need it, so I have to "refresh" or "redownload" it from the database. Is there any way to do this with only the object "doc"?

Comment: If you want to update on a current object, then you can use findAndModify command.  What is your requirement?

Comment: Lets say that I have two servers running that modify the database constantly and need the newest information but they only have the document.

Comment: OK, if I understand your requirement correctly, if you just need to update the document, then you have to use the findAndModify API to update on the latest document.  If you want to do other ways, then you have to custom code with some lock field in the document.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit better because I don't get it. what method of 'doc' should I use?

Comment: Check [this solution](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7781#issuecomment-491194033).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `doc` contains the document instance to refresh, you can do this to generically refresh it:

```
doc.model(doc.constructor.modelName).findOne({_id: doc._id},
    function(err, newDoc) {
        if (!err) {
            doc = newDoc;
        }
    }
);
```

However, it's better to not persist/cache Mongoose document instances beyond your immediate need for them.  Cache the immutable `_id` of docs you need to quickly access, not the docs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I know this is old but I have a better solution in case anyone else is still looking around.

What you can do in this situation of concurrent access to the same document is perform a normal save.

Mongoose uses the __v property of an object to make sure old instances don't overwrite the newest ones.

So if you have 2 instances of doc.__v = 0, and A saves first, the db now has doc.__v = 1.  So that when B saves, it'll error and because B.__v = 0, not 1.  So what you can do is then catch the error (it should be a specific mongoose error) and handle it by refreshing the object, (which should bump it up to __v = 1) then either SAVE it or not SAVE it depending on what you want to do.

so in code

```
doc.save(function (err, _doc) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.some_error_property_telling_you_version_was_wrong) {
            // Do your business here 
            // Refresh your object
            // Model.findById(doc._id, function (err, _refreshed_doc) {});
            // doc = _refreshed_doc;
            // doc.set('property', value); set the value again
            // Then re-save? or maybe make this a recursive function,
            // so it can keep trying to save the object?
        } else {
            // Handle it like a normal error
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's defined with `let` you can just do

```js
await thing.update(stuff);
thing = await Thing.findById(thing._id);
```

or if it was with `const` then do it immutably:

```js
await thing.update(stuff);
const updatedThing = await Thing.findById(thing._id);
```