# Reload document from database in Mongoose inside the instatiated object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a problem in my Nodejs project with Mongoose as the ORM. I am logging some requests between the client and the server. When I receive a response from a client, I issue another request, and from time to time I get a `VersionError: No matching document found in Mongoose`.

This is caused by the versioning system in Mongoose, as explained here: [Versioning in Mongoose](http://tgriff3.com/post/44230656391/versioning-in-mongoose).

So, I'd really like to follow his advice and do something like this:

```
ExampleSchema.methods.update_doc = function(callback) {
    this.save(function(err, video) { 
        if(err) { 
            if(err instanceof mongoose.Error.VersionError) {
                reload mongoose document and repeat save process
            }
            callback.call(self, err);
        } else {
            callback.call(self, null);
        }
    });
}
```

But how can I reload the document inside the object method?

Comment: Use `update` instead of `save` if possible.

Comment: Why should I use `update` instead of `save`?

Comment: @franzlorenzon "`.save()` watches and cares about version controls, while `.update()` will update the object regardless of version control." See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id Yet, that does not answer the original question, as `.update()` would overwrite any changes made by concurrent access. One alternative is to load the object again, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961303/mongoosejs-refresh-a-document Have you found a solution?

Comment: It's an old project, so unfortunely I can't verify the solution (and I don't remember what I did), since I'm not working anymore on it. Thanks anyway!