# Mongoose - Version Error: No matching document found for id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

**Context**: I have a `Post` Mongoose model that contains a `csv_files` array field to store csv strings. I make a `fetch` API request from a different web app to POST the csv strings for a particular `Post`.

The code below produces an error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): VersionError: No matching document found for id "5966932399e969ad8013bedf"

**router.js**

```
router.post('/posts/:url/upload-csv/:csv_name', (req, res) => {
  let csv_name = req.params.csv_name;
  let csv_string = csv_name+req.body.csv_string;

  Post.findOne({url: req.params.url})
    .then((post) => {
      if (post.csv_files.length === 0) {
        post.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      } else {
        let foundExistingCSV = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < post.csv_files.length; i++) {
          if (post.csv_files[i].includes(csv_name)) {
            foundExistingCSV = true;
            post.csv_files[i] = csv_string;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!foundExistingCSV) post.csv_files.push(csv_string);
      }

      post.markModified('csv_files');
      post.save();

      return res.status(200);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400);
    });
});
```

**models/post.js**

```
const mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var stringPreset = {
  type: String,
  uppercase: true
}

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  name                 : stringPreset,
  url                  : String,
  password             : String,
  csv_files            : { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  updatedAt            : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = { Post };
```

How can I fix this so that the document saves into the `csv_files` array without the error?

Comment: Is it possible that multiple requests are causing the same document to get processed (almost) concurrently?

Comment: @robertklep Checking concurrent access fixed my problem, thanks! Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 54):

When saving an object to Mongo DB you have to understand that Mongo DB has a version control system in place. This helps ensure that if you save an object once, when saving it again you don't end up overwriting the previously saved data.

This is the error you're seeing. If you want to force the object to update regardless of version control in this particular instance you may want to use **.update()** instead. This will force the object to be updated regardless of its currently saved state.

This is because **.save()** watches and cares about version controls, while **.update()** will update the object regardless of version control.

Comment: OK, this answer solved my actual question. But it brought me a new error. `MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'`

Comment: @dacopenhagen @ru4ert I had an migration and also some direct queries in mongodb shell on a collection and now i have documents with different __v (some of them are 4 and some of them are 5).

Now when i try to update for the first time i got this error, but in the second try it updates it successfully.

And is it a good idea to remove all `__v`s field or update all documents to an specific version.
something like this: `db.collectionName.updateMany({}, { __v: 5 })`

Answer (score 7):

I deleted version property from requests for update at body.

> delete req.body.__v;

Answer (score 3):

While it would appear a .save() is the right approach here, an .update() command would get the job done while ignoring "race conditions" that cause this error to occur. Mongo DB is throwing this error because it is concerned that I am saving an older version of the document that has already been updated:

v1 is sent to client
v1 is saved, and updated to v2 in Mongo DB
v1 is trying to be saved again, but Mongo DB already has v2 stored, error is thrown
A better approach is to send v1 to the client and when the cart object changes, synchronize the object with the new cart object no matter what. This can be done via .update() rather than through .save().

This is because .save() watches and cares about version controls, while .update() will update the object regardless of version control.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @robertklep was right. I fixed my issue by wrapping the first API call in a `Promise` and then executing the second API call after the first one completed.

I'll wait to mark this as the answer just in case anyone comes across a better solution.

Comment: I had an migration and also some direct queries in mongodb shell on a collection and now i have documents with different `__v` (some of them are *4* and some of them are *5*). Now when i try to update for the first time i got this error, but in the second try it updates it successfully. And is it a good idea to remove all `__v`s field or update all documents to an specific version. something like this: `db.collectionName.updateMany({}, { __v: 5 })`

Answer (score 0):

just to comment here what my problem apparently was.

**Error Message:**

> message: 'No matching document found for id "5c86d3a15bbcb965d85d80d1"
>   version 3',   name: 'VersionError',   version: 3

**My code:**

```
update: function (data) {

        var session = new Session(data);
        database.logging("INFO", "session-update", session.cid, session.order.orderNumber);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            session.save()
                .then(savedSession => resolve(savedSession))
                .catch(savedSessionError => reject(savedSessionError))
        });

    }
```

My parameter 'data' was already a Mongoose object and I was creating a new one and trying to *save()* it. So like @dacopenhagen said, *save()* checks the version of the document and it's throwing an VersionError error.

**How I fixed it**
Just removing the creation of the *Session()* object. 
Removed this line

```
var session = new Session(data);
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error.
I used findone.exec(). it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).