# No matching document found for id error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing two issues with the below code

1. Upon saving the document after put API call,it's throwing a message **' No matching document found for id \"59c6607a1608fe26e8c7f574\"" '**
2. If required attribute value for each field is set as true then mongoose is throwing a validation error message stating that path not found.For eg if ii set addressLine1: { type: String, required: true } then it throws a validation message contact.addressLine1: Path `contact.addressLine1` is required.However if required attribute is set to false then no validation error is thrown.

Can some one help me to correct the below code -

Model -

```
var localTransportSchema = new Schema({
    providerID: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: false
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: false
    },
    contact: {
        addressLine1: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        addressLine2: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        postalCode: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        primaryContactNumber: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        secondaryContactNumber: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        serviceActiveFlag: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            enum: ['Y', 'N']
        },
    },
    vehicle: [{
        vehicleType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            enum: ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'suv', 'mpv', 'luxury']
        },
        activeFlag: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            enum: ['Y', 'N']
        },
    }]
});
```

Controller -

```
module.exports.updateLocalTransportVendorDtls = function(req, res) {
    var transportSchema = new transportModel();
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            checkForNewVehicleType(req, function(doc) {
                resolve(doc)
            })
        })
        .then(function(doc) {
            var updateJustServiceDtls = doc.split(/\|/)[2];

            return addJustNewVehicleDetailsOnly(req, res)

        }).then(function() {
            transportSchema.save(function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details collection: - " + error.message)
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        "Message": error.message.trim()
                    });
                }
            })

        }).catch(function(err) {
            return res.json({
                "Message": err.message
            });
        });
}
```

Function -

```
var addJustNewVehicleDetailsOnly = function(req, res) {

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var updates = {
            $set: {
                "contact": {
                    "addressLine2": req.body['addressLine2'],
                    "secondaryContactNumber": req.body['secondaryContactNumber'],
                    "serviceActiveFlag": req.body['serviceActiveFlag']
                },
                "$push": {
                    "vehicle": {
                        "vehicleType": req.body['vehicleType'],
                        "chargePerKiloMeter": req.body['chargePerKM'],
                        "selfDriven": req.body['isSelfDriven'],
                        "additionalCharges": req.body['additionalCharges'],
                        "driverBata": req.body['driverBata'],
                        "activeFlag": req.body['vehicleActiveFlag']
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        transportModel.findOneAndUpdate({
                "name": req.body['providerName'],
                "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode'])
            },
            updates, {
                returnOriginal: false,
                upsert: false
            },
            function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " in transport details table"
                    }));
                } else if (doc === null) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details : - unable to update database");
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " due to " + err.message
                    }));
                }
                return resolve();
            });

    })
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: (2) Are you talking about validation on the `update` object? If so then I think it would make sense to have different JSON schemas for updates and for full objects. For `update` you want `required: false`; if you're validating an object you'd want `required: true`.

Comment: Is this the way schemas are handled in big projects?I mean one for create and another one for update?

Comment: I have been in this situation, but I don't honestly remember how we handled it. But two schemas seems viable to me. On the one hand, a document must have an `addressLine1`, so you might as well put `required: true` in the document schema; on the other hand, updates aren't required to have it, so they need `required: false`. But alternatively, you could take the attitude that it's not worth maintaining two separate schemas, and just have `required: false`; then you'd have to do an extra bit of validation in the code (namely, on document creation, check that these fields exist).

Comment: Possible duplicate for the first problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id