# NodeJS Mongoose update document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update or create a document in a MongoDB collection, using "mongoose" this way :

```
        this.statsModel.findOne(
            {product_id: requestData.ean},
        ).then((stats: mongoose.Schema) => {
            const productId: string = requestData.ean;
            // Update stats with the new scan...
            const beforeStats: mongoose.Schema = stats;

            const scan: any = {
                coords: {
                    lat: requestData.lat,
                    lon: requestData.lon,
                },
                at: new Date(),
            };

            if (stats) {
                stats.scans.push(scan);
                stats.update();
            } else {
                const newStat = new this.statsModel();
                newStat._id = requestData.ean;
                newStat.product_id = requestData.ean;
                newStat.scans = [scan];
                newStat.purchases = [];
                newStat.save();
            }
```

When this code runs, no new element appears in the "scans" property if had a stats document.

The document is properly created if the stats document was not found.

I tried to change "update()" method to "save()" method, but, this way, i got a "Version error No matching document for the id..."

What i'm doing wrong ?

Regards...

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id

Comment: Already checked, but didn't answer to this issue... In my case, "stats" is already a Mongo Document, so, according to the doc, i may save it and don't have to create another document before do it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, update the type of the stats promised to Model instead of mongoose.Schema :

```
        this.statsModel.findOne(
            {product_id: requestData.ean},
        ).then((stats: Model<Stats>) => {
            const productId: string = requestData.ean;
            // Update stats with the new scan...
            const beforeStats: mongoose.Schema = stats;

            const scan: any = {
                coords: {
                    lat: requestData.lat,
                    lon: requestData.lon,
                },
                at: new Date(),
            };

            if (stats) {
                stats.scans.push(scan);
                stats.save();
            } else {
                const newStat = new this.statsModel();
                newStat._id = requestData.ean;
                newStat.product_id = requestData.ean;
                newStat.scans = [scan];
                newStat.purchases = [];
                newStat.save();
            }
```

So the save() method properly works...

Thx