# Mongoose .save function returning 'No matching document found for id "32fdj..." version 0 modifiedPaths "cmRooms"'

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
    let property = await PropertyModel.findOne({
      propertyId: res.locals.userInformations.userId
    });

    let cmRooms = property.cmRooms;
    const newCmRooms = cmRooms.filter(
      cmRoom => cmRoom.cmRoomId !== "1234";
    );

    property.cmRooms = newCmRooms;
    await property.save(err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

I am getting the following error

> message:    'No matching document found for id
>   "5eb7638320ab5d0633477081" version 0 modifiedPaths "cmRooms"',
>
> name: 'VersionError',   version: 0,
>
> modifiedPaths: [ 'cmRooms' ] }

Comment: 1) closing brackets of findOne is missing 2)i believe you cant use findOne on a schema. You have to make a model using - let Prop = mongoose.model('Property',PropertySchema); Prop.findOne({...})

Comment: Actully it model, bad naming convention !! i am able find all properties,

Comment: let property = await PropertyModel.findOne({
      propertyId: res.locals.userInformations.userId
    }).exec(); //note the .exec()

Comment: that is also not helping !

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose - Version Error: No matching document found for id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the above code to this and try:

```
await PropertyModel.findOne({
    propertyId: res.locals.userInformations.userId
}, async function (err, property) {
    if (!err) {
        let cmRooms = property.cmRooms;
        const newCmRooms = cmRooms.filter(
            cmRoom => cmRoom.cmRoomId !== "1234"
        );

        property.cmRooms = newCmRooms;
        await property.save(err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```