# MongoDB error no matching document found for id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Nodejs server and mongodb I go to save a change to Select model like this:

```
const selectModel = await dbs.Select.findOne({ relatedAccount: id, movie }); 
await selectModel.save();
```

It works fine 99 percent of times but sometimes I get this error:

> VersionError: No matching document found for id "id_here" version 1628 modifiedPaths "colors, colors.171, colors.171.red"

I tried to fix it using `update` method instead of `save` method:

I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223025/mongoose-version-error-no-matching-document-found-for-id).

`await selectModel.update();`

But it returns this error **each time**:

> TypeError: selectModel.update is not a function

Comment: Can you share some more of your code please. In particular, the route that this `findOne` function executes in and how you create your models?

Comment: Check out the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html. A mongoose Model has `updateOne` and `updateMany` methods, but not `update`